# How to enable CORS in a community

Tags: community, api, security, org, cors

Hi i've recently encountered a problem where i needed CORS to be enabled for some domains. In the Salesforce Org i can specify CORS to be enabled for some domains. The problem lies with community users. They still get the CORS problem. Is there a way to enable CORS for some domains inside a community? Thanks in advance :)